# Unable to install Docker for Windows for the Divio App

Tags: django, docker, content-management-system, django-cms, boot2docker

When trying to set up the Divio app, I get this warning screen.
[DivioSetupWarningScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EojFV.jpg)

However, even though the picture claims I do, I don't have Docker Toolbox installed. When I try to install Docker for Windows on anyways by pressing the "Continue" button as seen in the picture above, I get this. 
[DockerNotInstalled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzCL6.jpg)

In the second picture, I tried clicking "Contact Support," but that led me to a blank webpage. Also, if I try to install Docker Windows without the Divio App, but it would not let me because I do not have the enterprise Windows OS, just the home. I also tried downloading Boot2Docker Start, but that didn't really help.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: @user3579867 what "blank webpage" did _Contact Support_ take you to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have Windows Home edition, one of the solutions would be to install Docker Toolbox/VirtualBox manually and use Divio CLI in PowerShell. Because current version of Divio App does not recognize Windows edition type. It should be presented in the next coming release.